# Observable onNext() method never get called with singleSubscriber

Tags: android, rx-java

I have one `BehaviourSubject` which chained another `Observable` using `flatMap`. If Subscription is done through `singleSubscrier`, `onNext()` method never get called. Once replaced with `Observer` or `Subscriber`, start receiving `onNext()` call.

#### Does it because chained observable emitted more than once ?

```
private Observable<chatObject> getObservable() {
    return loadBehaviorSubject()
            .flatMap(new Func1<chatObject, Observable<chatObject>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<chatObject> call(final chatObject object) {

                    return chaninedObservable.map(
                            new Func1<chatObject, ChatObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public ChatObject call(chatObject object) {
                                    // do some operations here 
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Please post the code of this `singleSubscrier` and how you use it. Please post the replaced code with `Observer` or `Subscriber`. If `onNext` is not called, make sure you don't reuse a `Subscriber`, make sure there is actually data available in `chaninedObservable` and make sure you give the code enough time to run if it is asynchronous and you test it via a plain main() method or unit test.